# How to check if email exists

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get an error that says that the email exists already and I'm trying to use jquery. I'm using ajax and it does work, because when I use firebug and I go to the console it says that the email address exists but I would like that to appear on the page.

index.php

```
<div class="register-newsletter">
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="enter email address" required>
    <input type="image" value="SUBMIT" id="sub" src="images/register.jpg">
 </form>

<a class="newsletter" href="javascript:void(0);">Add to e-mailing list</a>
```

This is my jquery

```
$("#email").click(function(){
    if($.trim($(this).val() ) == "enter email address"){
        $(this).val("");
    }
})

$("#email").blur(function(){
    if($.trim($(this).val() ) == ""){
        $(this).val("enter email address");
    }
})

$("#sub").click(function () {

    var email = $.trim($("#email").val());
    if(email == "" || !isValidEmailAddress(email)){
        alert('enter valid email');
        return false;
    }

    var ajaxid = ajax("ajax/userInfo.php","email="+encodeURIComponent(email));
    $("#result").html($.trim(ajaxid));

});

$("#myForm").submit(function () {
    return false;
});

function clearInput() {

    $("#myForm :input").val('');
}

$('p').hide();
$('#myForm').hide();
$(".newsletter").click(function(){
    $(".newsletter").hide();
    $('#myForm').show();
});
$('#myForm').submit(function(){
    $('#myForm').hide();
    $('p').show(); 
});
```

and this is my userInfo.php

```
<?php
include("../config.php");
global $_NEWSLETTER_CUSTOMERS_TABLE;

$email = $_POST['email'];
//$email = html_entity_decode(str_replace("'", "\'", $_POST["email"]));

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $_NEWSLETTER_CUSTOMERS_TABLE WHERE `email` = '".$email."'");
if(mysql_num_rows($query) >0){
echo '<span class="exists">Email address arleady exists</span>';
} else {

if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO $_NEWSLETTER_CUSTOMERS_TABLE(email) VALUES('$email')"))
    echo "Successfully Inserted";
else
    echo "Insertion Failed";
}
```

Comment: Adding a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your question can help people a lot. :)

Answer (score 4):

You are attempting to append the data incorrectly. jQuery's `ajax()` method takes a function that will be called upon the success of the request, called `success`. At the moment, you are trying to append `ajaxid`, (which contains `ajax()`s return value, not the result of the request) to `#result`.

```
var ajaxid = ajax("ajax/userInfo.php","email="+encodeURIComponent(email));
$("#result").html($.trim(ajaxid));
```

Should be more like:

```
var ajaxid = ajax("ajax/userInfo.php", {
    data:"email="+encodeURIComponent(email),
    success:function(d){
        $("#result").html($.trim(d));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) inside your click handler:

```
$.post('ajax/userInfo.php', { email: email }, function(data) {
  alert(data.message);
}, 'json');
```

And in your PHP file instead of `echo` use:

```
$response = array();
$response['message'] = mysql_query("...") ? 'success' : 'fail';
return json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must return the value, eg JSON

Your JS

```
$("#sub").click(function () {
$.ajax({
      url      : "ajax/userInfo.php",
      dataType : "json",
      error    : function(request, error) {    
                   alert("Erreur : responseText: "+request.responseText);
                 },
      success  : function(data) { 
                   alert(data.email_exist); 
                   $("#result").html(data.email_exist);
                 }      
 });
```

});

AND your PHP

```
if(mysql_num_rows($query) >0){
  $result = array(
   'email_exist' => 'Email address arleady exists'
  );
}
json_encode($result);
```